# "Retro"is a namespace But used as type

Tags: c#

So im A Roblox Exploiter That Is Making an Exploit But When I tried to Start Debugging its giving me this error code CS0118

> ```
> using rtexecute;
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using Retro;
> namespace Retro
> {
>     static class Program
>     {
>         /// <summary>
>         /// The main entry point for the application.
>         /// </summary>
>         [STAThread]
>         static void Main()
>         {
>             Application.EnableVisualStyles();
>             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
>             Application.Run(new Retro());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

And Get Error Retro Is a Namespace but used as a type
plz helpim new plz plz plz plz

Comment: It happens when class name is same as namespace. Since Retro is the namespace, Can you try to rename Retro class name to something else..

Comment: You get this error because you've used the name `Retro` as the namespace in your program in the line `namespace Retro`. You can change that. Or if you'd like to keep it, you can change `Application.Run(new Retro());` to `Application.Run(new Retro.Retro());`

Comment: Add then replace new Retro() instance with new class name.. Let's say new class name is Retro2 then replace it with new Retro2()

Comment: Remove that `using Retro;` and rename you starting Form to something like `RetroMain`, `RetroForm`, `frmRetro`, `MainForm` or whatever. It's not really a good idea to have a Form named as the namespace it belongs to, it creates a long series of problems internally.

Comment: There's no `Retro` type in the code you posted. Only a namespace. And you use the namespace name `Retro` in a place where a type is expected (i.e. `new Retro()`). So, the error message is clear enough given the context. For a more detailed discussion of dealing with ambiguity when the code (unlikely what you've posted here) actually has both a namespace and a type with the same name, see duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using static

```
using static Retro.Retro;
```

or

```
using Retro = Retro.Retro;
```

You can change the naming of Retro before the equal sign by any name.